# Checking the address family in socket programming

Tags: c, ipv6

what will be the output of the following code :

```
char peer_ip[16];
inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1",peer_ip);
```

now I have peer_ip in network form. How can I check what is the address family ??? I cannot use inet_ntop now. Is there any way ?? Will getaddrinfo work in this case ???

Comment: You can't recover the address family from the buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go higher up and use `getaddrinfo` instead of `inet_pton` (which doesn't handle IPv6 scopes) and instead of opaque buffers use `struct sockaddr_storage` and `struct sockaddr` pointers then you can immediately determine the family with `ss.ss_family` or `sa.sa_family` as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

You can't—`inet_pton` gives you either a `struct in_addr` (for `AF_INET`) or a `struct in6_addr` (for `AF_INET6`), depending on what address family you pass in.  If you consider these structures to be binary blobs of memory, there's no way you can recover the address family from them, you just have to keep track of what type of binary blob you have.

You should really be using a `struct in_addr`, not a `char[16]` as the value passed into `inet_pton`:

```
struct in_addr peer_ip;
inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &peer_ip);
```